# How can I fix the "Cannot parse result path string:" error in android studio version 3.6.2 on running the application?

Tags: java, android-studio, debugging, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to run/debug the application in android studio version 3.6.2 but returning an error saying Cannot parse result path string:

Build output box shows:

Build failed:
Cannot parse result path string:

Comment: Add details of the question please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is with the gradle version
I simply had to switch from version 6.5 to 6.5.1 and after rebuilding it worked just fine.

If you are on windows go File -> Project Structure, on project change the gradle version.

Comment: I had to clean project after updating the Gradle version to make it work.

Comment: yes thanks i tried everything except this but lastly i use this and it worked

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be the gradle version. Using a gradle version above 6.5 should fix the problem to allow the build to complete. If the problem persists, I would suggest reinstalling android studio with updated gradle version.

To change gradle version: Navigate to file-> project structure and access the dropdown menu besides gradle.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Gradle cache. Try below methods:

**Method1:** Try the invalidate cache/restart option from menu.

**Method2:** Clear the Gradle cache manually by deleting `caches` from `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches`.

Comment: Method 2 worked for me; actually, deleting subfolder 8.4 was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle project >>update dependencies classpath .

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

update the latest build gradle Kotlin version in build.gradle file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).